# What makes the 1D Fuel Scoop superior to the 1E Fuel Scoop?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm looking to purchase my first fuel scoop, and I have a few options available to me given my current financial situation. One thing that has me really confused, though, is the pricing between the 1E and 1D fuel scoops. As far as I can tell the 1E is superior to the 1D,  due to it consuming less energy and having higher integrity, but it costs significantly less and is  a lower rating.

I feel as if I must be greatly misunderstanding what some of these attributes means, because the pricing and rating between these two items just doesn't make any sense at all.

What am I missing or misunderstanding that makes the 1D scoop superior to the 1E?

[image]

[image: 1D Fuel Scoop]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a rounding artifact of the shop UI displaying the rate as metric tons/second instead of the actual scoop rate of kg/second.

In the [case of the 1E and 1D scoops](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Fuel_Scoop#Fuel_Scoop_Specifications), the rates are 18 kg/s and 24 kg/s, which both unfortunately round to 0.02 tons/s with the number of decimal places shown. So the 1D scoop does have a marginally better scoop rate, at the cost of additional power consumption (and credits).

Comment: Assuming a Sidewinder, that's a difference of 1m51s and 1m23s for max rate scooping to fill a completely fuel tank.

Comment: 'D' Variants are generally the 'lightweight' module for that size bracket, but has fuel scoops are not considered in mass, they have no effect on Jump range.

Comment: Shame they don't show the kg/s stat in the shop; until you get to size 4+ scoops the t/s really aren't high enough to be useful display numbers. Especially considering they do show them in the HUD display while you were actually scooping; I'd always wondered how those much higher numbers actually corresponded to the scoop rate I saw in the shop, didn't actually realise it was simply kg/s until I saw this answer.

Comment: The difference is easier to see if you have one or the other already installed. The module comparison will show how much better or worse the other version is.